# How to get LLDB to step into operator<< of std::cout?

Tags: c++, debugging, lldb

I am using ArchLinux and debug infos are installed (repository urls added to /etc/pacman.conf, and `paru -S glibc-debug gcc-debug`).

I have created a file called `hello.cpp`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "こんにちは" << std::endl;
}
```

After running `clang++ -g hello.cpp`, I debugged `a.out` with both `gdb` and `lldb`, which made me find only LLDB could not step into the operator<< of std::cout.

I executed `gdb` and some inner commands.

```
> gdb a.out
(gdb) b main
(gdb) r
(gdb) s
```

The output was like this. You can see that GDB can trace inside the operator<<.

```
❯ gdb a.out
GNU gdb (GDB) 13.1
Copyright (C) 2023 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-pc-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from a.out...
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x114d: file hello.cpp, line 4.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /***/a.out 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/usr/lib/libthread_db.so.1".

Breakpoint 1, main () at hello.cpp:4
4           std::cout << "こんにちは" << std::endl;
(gdb) s
std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> > (__out=..., __s=0x555555556004 "こんにちは") at /usr/src/debug/gcc/gcc-build/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/ostream:662
662         operator<<(basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& __out, const char* __s)
(gdb)
```

On the other hand, when I tried to do the same thing with LLDB,

```
> lldb a.out
(lldb) b main
(lldb) r
(lldb) s
```

the line of `std::cout` was entirely skipped.

```
❯ lldb a.out
(lldb) target create "a.out"
Current executable set to '/***/a.out' (x86_64).
(lldb) b main
Breakpoint 1: where = a.out`main + 4 at hello.cpp:4:18, address = 0x000000000000114d
(lldb) r
Process 347983 launched: '/***/a.out' (x86_64)
Process 347983 stopped
* thread #1, name = 'a.out', stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
    frame #0: 0x000055555555514d a.out`main at hello.cpp:4:18
   1    #include <iostream>
   2   
   3    int main() {
-> 4        std::cout << "こんにちは" << std::endl;
   5    }
(lldb) s
こんにちはProcess 347983 stopped
* thread #1, name = 'a.out', stop reason = step in
    frame #0: 0x0000555555555178 a.out`main at hello.cpp:5:1
   2   
   3    int main() {
   4        std::cout << "こんにちは" << std::endl;
-> 5    }
(lldb)
```

I think LLDB is originally supposed to be able to debug functions in the standard library.

Is this a correct behavior? Is there a way to step into operator<< of std::cout with LLDB?

---

#### Outputs

```
❯ /usr/bin/g++ -g -v hello.cpp
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.1.1/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Configured with: /build/gcc/src/gcc/configure --enable-languages=ada,c,c++,d,fortran,go,lto,objc,obj-c++ --enable-bootstrap --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=https://bugs.archlinux.org/ --with-build-config=bootstrap-lto --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --enable-cet=auto --enable-checking=release --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-default-pie --enable-default-ssp --enable-gnu-indirect-function --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-libstdcxx-backtrace --enable-link-serialization=1 --enable-linker-build-id --enable-lto --enable-multilib --enable-plugin --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --disable-libssp --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-werror
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 13.1.1 20230429 (GCC) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-g' '-v' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64' '-dumpdir' 'a-'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.1.1/cc1plus -quiet -v -D_GNU_SOURCE hello.cpp -quiet -dumpdir a- -dumpbase hello.cpp -dumpbase-ext .cpp -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -g -version -o /tmp/cc0gSOV9.s
GNU C++17 (GCC) version 13.1.1 20230429 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
        compiled by GNU C version 13.1.1 20230429, GMP version 6.2.1, MPFR version 4.2.0, MPC version 1.3.1, isl version isl-0.26-GMP

warning: MPFR header version 4.2.0 differs from library version 4.2.0-p9.
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.1.1/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.1.1/../../../../include/c++/13.1.1
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.1.1/../../../../include/c++/13.1.1/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.1.1/../../../../include/c++/13.1.1/backward
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.1.1/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.1.1/include-fixed
 /usr/include
End of search list.
Compiler executable checksum: e149eaca55f4ee2a0171ba2b54b0dc8d
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-g' '-v' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64' '-dumpdir' 'a-'
 as -v --gdwarf-5 --64 -o /tmp/cc5MF67V.o /tmp/cc0gSOV9.s
GNU assembler version 2.40.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) using BFD version (GNU Binutils) 2.40.0
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.1.1/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.1.1/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.1.1/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.1.1/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.1.1/../../../../lib/:/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.1.1/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-g' '-v' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64' '-dumpdir' 'a.'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.1.1/collect2 -plugin /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.1.1/liblto_plugin.so -plugin-opt=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.1.1/lto-wrapper -plugin-opt=-fresolution=/tmp/cctNfJ8Z.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc --build-id --eh-frame-hdr --hash-style=gnu -m elf_x86_64 -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -pie /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.1.1/../../../../lib/Scrt1.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.1.1/../../../../lib/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.1.1/crtbeginS.o -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.1.1 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.1.1/../../../../lib -L/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.1.1/../../.. /tmp/cc5MF67V.o -lstdc++ -lm -lgcc_s -lgcc -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.1.1/crtendS.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.1.1/../../../../lib/crtn.o
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-g' '-v' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64' '-dumpdir' 'a.'

❯ /usr/bin/gdb --version
GNU gdb (GDB) 13.1
Copyright (C) 2023 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

❯ /usr/bin/lldb --version
lldb version 15.0.7

❯ ldd a.out
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffcfaff6000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f0751800000)
        libm.so.6 => /usr/lib/libm.so.6 (0x00007f0751a98000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f07517db000)
        libc.so.6 => /usr/lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007f07515f1000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 => /usr/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f0751bc6000)

❯ nm -C a.out
0000000000003da8 d _DYNAMIC
0000000000003fe8 d _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
0000000000002000 R _IO_stdin_used
                 w _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
                 w _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
                 U std::ostream::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))@GLIBCXX_3.4
0000000000002014 r std::__detail::__integer_to_chars_is_unsigned<unsigned int>
0000000000002015 r std::__detail::__integer_to_chars_is_unsigned<unsigned long>
0000000000002016 r std::__detail::__integer_to_chars_is_unsigned<unsigned long long>
0000000000004040 B std::cout@GLIBCXX_3.4
                 U std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)@GLIBCXX_3.4
                 U std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)@GLIBCXX_3.4
0000000000002018 r __GNU_EH_FRAME_HDR
0000000000004020 D __TMC_END__
0000000000004020 B __bss_start
                 w __cxa_finalize@GLIBC_2.2.5
0000000000004010 D __data_start
0000000000004018 D __dso_handle
                 w __gmon_start__
                 U __libc_start_main@GLIBC_2.34
0000000000004020 D _edata
0000000000004158 B _end
0000000000001180 T _fini
0000000000001000 T _init
0000000000001050 T _start
0000000000004010 W data_start
0000000000001149 T main
```

Comment: I suspect there is a default setting that skips the standard library while debugging, try lurking around [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13213341). Similar to Visual Studio's "Just My Code" or `.natstepfilter`

Comment: This is a dup of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70554765/why-the-breakpoints-set-in-stl-are-skipped-ignored-while-using-lldb/70560542#70560542

Comment: @yeputons & JimIngham Now I know that LLDB by default skips functions whose names start with `std::`. Thank you for teaching me!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for commenting. [@Jim Ingham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2465073/jim-ingham) has already provided a solution in https://stackoverflow.com/a/70560542/22234700.

The answer explains that the behavior is the default of LLDB and can be controlled by setting `target.process.thread.step-avoid-regexp`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).